# Showing Null Pointer Exception Calling From Static Method Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, static-methods

There are three class History, Databasehandlreone, DatabaseHandler. In History call there is one static method named addHistory(Record record). it calling the non static method which is in same class named calling(String u).

History

```
    class History extends Activity{
    public static long addHistory(Record record) {
    String u=record.getURL();
    History ss=new History();
    ss.calling(u);
    }
    private void calling(String u) {
            DatabaseHandlerone db=new DatabaseHandlerone(History.this);
            try{
            db.good(u); 
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.v("Error",e.toString());
            }}}
```

In calling function, it calls the function named good which is in another class name Databasehandlerone.

DatabaseHandlerone.java

```
    public class DatabaseHandlerone {
        public DatabaseHandlerone(History history) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    public void good(String s){
            try{
            DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(DatabaseHandlerone.this);
            db.deleteall(s); 
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.v("Calling from DatabseHandler1",e.toString());
            }   }
```

In good function, deleteall function will be called which is another class called DatabaseHandler.

When I am calling db.deleteall(s). It showing Java.NullPointerException error. can anyone pls Help.

DatabseHandler.this

```
    public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
         public void deleteall(String s){
          Log.v("value",s);
         }
```

Logcat

```
            02-21 11:46:35.941: D/libc-netbsd(22197): getaddrinfo: stackoverflow.com get result from proxy >>
            02-21 11:46:35.943: D/ID Safe Utils(22197): leave sendOpenUrlBroadcast
            02-21 11:46:35.959: V/Good(22197): http://stackoverflow.com/users
            02-21 11:46:35.959: V/Calling(22197): http://stackoverflow.com/users
            02-21 11:46:35.959: V/After Databse(22197): After DatabseHandler Calling
            02-21 11:46:35.959: V/Value(22197): http://stackoverflow.com/users
            02-21 11:46:35.959: V/String(22197): http://stackoverflow.com/users
            02-21 11:46:35.960: V/DatabaseHandler()(22197): Afert SdCard
            02-21 11:46:35.960: V/Calling from DatabseHandler1(22197): java.lang.NullPointerException
            02-21 11:46:35.960: V/DatabaseHandler()(22197): Afert SdCard
            02-21 11:46:35.960: V/Retreiving Values:(22197): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: can you show your logcat?

Comment: Where is `deleteall(String s)` defined?

Comment: where is deleteall(-) defination?

Comment: deleteall is in DatabaseHandler class

Comment: Not deleteall(), where is deleteall(String s)?

Comment: where is the `return` statement of `long addHistory()` method?

Comment: Why not print the exception's stack trace somewhere? (Or log the whole exception)

Comment: can you post full logcat?

Comment: Post more code.. e.g constructor of `DatabaseHandler`, what you do in `deleteall(String s)`, etc..

Comment: Constructor and all working fine when call deleteall then it shows null pointer exception

Comment: see i posted full logcat... @Nag

Comment: `public static long addHistory` why did you put this in an `Activity`?  Are you aware of why this can be dangerous?  You should not try to treat activities like POJOs.  Instead, create a separate class to handle the history.

Comment: You posted some random part of logcat.  Please learn a) how to use the debugger.  It is madness to try to develop apps without it b) what a stack trace is, c) how to find it in the logcat d) how to read it

Comment: Yes u are rite thank u @Simon...